# Visual studio 2019 default .net core version

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, .net-5

For some reason Visual Studio do not offer any option to choose framework versión when creating a new library or console project for .Net core. It does for .Net framework.

[image: .Net Core new project]

[image: .Net Framework new project]

Now that .Net 5 has been released I want all my project to use this latest versión by default. I know I can modify it later, but I'd like it to be default option (since I cannot choose).

Is it possible to change this default behaviour? Is there any reason Visual Studio won't let us to choose framework version for .Net Core?

BTW: I installed .Net 5 SDK recently, having installed Visual Studio 2019 one year ago. I'm not using pre-release versions.